# Error while parsing USD and $ amounts using money_get<>

Tags: c++

I am getting an error while parsing USD and $ amounts using money_get<>.

```
#include <iostream>         /// cin, cout
#include <locale>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cin.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    std::cout << "USD  1.11$2.22"
              << " parsed with the facet directly: ";

    auto& f = std::use_facet<std::money_get<char>>(cin.getloc());
    std::ios_base::iostate err;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> frm(cin), end;
    long double val;

    /// international currency symbol
    frm = f.get(frm, end, true, cin, err, val);
    std::cout << "\n "<< val/100;

    string str;
    cin >> str;
    cout << "\n remaining: " << str << endl;

    /// local currency symbol
    f.get(frm, end, false, cin, err, val);
    std::cout << "\n "<< val/100;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1f76385cbed6834

The input is:

```
USD  1.11
$2.22
```

The output is:

```
USD  1.11$2.22 parsed with the facet directly: 
 1.11
 remaining: .22
 0
```

The patterns from the corresponding moneypunct<> facet are:
  for USD: sign symbol space value
  for $: sign symbol value none

Obviously, I'm overshooting the mark when the 1st amount is read. I can't figure out why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have isolated the problem further.

It doesn't seem to be a problem of the get_money() manipulator or of the money_get<> facet.

It is an issue of string v/s cin - Input of monetary amounts specified using local currency(eg: $) works correctly from an istringstream but not from cin.

Please note that I have modified some of the following code from cppreference.com.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19e0fdc663c5d845

Input of monetary amounts specified using local currency(eg: $) works correctly from an istringstream:

```
string str = "$1.11 $2.22 $3.33 4.44 5.55";


void stringInput()          /// works
{
    cout << "string Input ... works:\n";

    istringstream s1(str);
    s1.imbue(locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << '"' << str << "\" parsed with the I/O manipulator: ";

    long double val;

    while(s1 >> get_money(val))
        cout << val/100 << ' ';

    cout << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
string Input ... works:
"$1.11 $2.22 $3.33 4.44 5.55" parsed with the I/O manipulator: 1.11 2.22 3.33 4.44 5.55
```

Input of monetary amounts specified using local currency(eg: $) works *incorrectly* from cin (same link):

```
void cinInput()             /// does not work
{
    cout << "cin Input ... doesn't work:\n";

    cin.imbue(locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << '"' << str << "\" parsed with the I/O manipulator: ";

    long double val;

    while(cin >> get_money(val))
        std::cout << val/100 << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
cin Input ... doesn't work:
"$1.11 $2.22 $3.33 4.44 5.55" parsed with the I/O manipulator: 0.11 0.22 0.33 0.44 0.55
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've finally precisely pinpointed the problem and solved it.

The root cause of the problem is not a C++ issue at all. cin, istringstream, get_money() and money_get<> all work just fine.

It's basically an input issue.

Consider the following input string:

```
$1.11 $2.22 $3.33 $4.44 $5.55
```

When entered *offline*, it is read perfectly correctly, as entered.

However, when entered *online*, the "$1", "$2", "$3", etc. are not read into the input. They are treated as special characters. This is why on coliru (and possibly any other online C++ engine), the $ amounts were not getting read correctly. This may be a UNIX issue, where $ is treated as a special character.

The solution is to escape it: instead of $, enter \$.

```
\$1.11 \$2.22 \$3.33 \$4.44 \$5.55
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2043935559f6d40

There's some junk on that link, but you can get the gist of it. The link pinpoints only the root cause of the problem. I shall use it to develop the complete solution and post that later.